# What do dots on a switching coil indicate?

Tags: circuit-design, inductor, coil

Noticed all these coils have a dot on one side of them. Same dots are on the schematics as well.

Is it purely for reference to one side of the circuit or is there another reason?

I know coils are just wound wire so I never thought "polarity" would be an issue? [image]

Comment: At least two of the dotted components look more like ceramic capacitors than coils.  Since the dots look the same on different components, I would guess that they weren't applied by the component manufacturers, but appeared during the PCB assembly.  [I haven't seen dots like this before.  So I'm curious what they might be for or from.]

Comment: Yeah it's strange and the same dots are referenced in the schematics. Only one one side of the coils

Comment: It may be that the dots do indicate polarity and are placed in a certain position to prevent coil coupling being counter productive to circuit performance. Coils placed so close can couple and if the coupling is "the wrong way round" it may deteriorate performance. Show a snippet of the circuit please.

Comment: @Andyaka How can a coil have polarity though? This is an iPhone and last time I posted a snippet from iPhone schematic I got backlash about being discreet. But for example one circuit for backlight shows the dot on the vcc_main side labeled 1 and the other end of coil with no dot labeled 2 on the "switching" side

Comment: Coils have polarity in that they couple their magnetic fields either constructively or destructively. As the distance increases the effects become very small but they can't be ignored when this close.

Comment: Even a spring has polarity. If you rotate the ends clockwise the spring may close up or it may expand.

Comment: @Andyaka Do you mean they're purposely made to have an input on the same end as every coil next to them so that the magnetic field is in the same direction when they're all being energized on and off by their switching circuits?

Comment: Possibly something like that but without a circuit etc....

Comment: @Andyaka, springs have the same symmetry as coils, it you fit one backwards it works just the same as forwards.

Comment: @Jasen not true in all cases. A company I worked for long ago reverse engineered a hinge that had an integral spring but, nobody bothered to think that when the hinge was forced open, the spring coils expanded a little. Result: the spring was made wrong and the coils contracted enough to grind onto the central member of the hinge and the hinge got half open and locked in place. I can't think of an electrical analogy off hand but it might involve diodes!

Answer (score 1):

A single coil doesn't have polarity, but multiple coils that are magnetically coupled do have polarity relative to each other.

For transformers where this would matter, the schematic shows a dot by one end of each coil.  If you put a signal into one winding from dot to not-dot, then the signal will come out with same polarity from the other winding also dot to not-dot.

As for the dots in the picture, I can't say since the picture is too blurred to show anything meaningful.

Comment: The dots in the picture are of multiple coils each on a different separate circuit. If that helps

Comment: @user: No.  A proper picture would help.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but the dots are actually telling you which direction the current should flow. You can pre-bias the magnetics in the inductor such that the inductor saturates at a higher current in one direction and lower current in the other. This is advantageous for high performance DC DC converters.

This was an interview question at a top level EE company, and I believe that board is from that same company ;)

I believe that inductor is this case, but there's another use for the inductor dot, which is to display where the coil is physically wound. Consulting the datasheet for that part may tell you what the dot actually means, like it might have diagrams to say "don't lay out two inductors from us like this, or they will couple more" kinda thing.